# Write access for a System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: .net, process, file-permissions, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostcript (GS) to modify PDF files, on a Windows 10 system, though I think I have a general problem, not really related to GS.

When I run GS from a command prompt, it works fine. When I try to do the same thing from a process created by C# code, I get an error. I suspect that the problem is caused by my process not having write access to the folder where the output file is being created.

My questions are:

1. How do I open up permissions on the target folder? To whom or what do I need to grant write access? I tried using Explorer to grant "Full Control" to "Everyone", but that didn't help.
2. Can I somehow give "super" powers to my process, so that it can write wherever it wants? (I'm not worried about security issues).

Here is the GS command (which works):

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite –q -o outFile.pdf -c "[/CropBox [72 72 144 216] /PAGES pdfmark" -f inFile.pdf
```

And here is my C# code that is trying to execute this same command (which doesn't work):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace pdfcropper
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         string gspath = @"D:\ciao\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\itextsharp\gswin64c.exe";

         ProcessStartInfo psi= new ProcessStartInfo(gspath);
         psi.UseShellExecute = false;
         psi.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\ciao\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\itextsharp";
         psi.Arguments = @" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH –q -o outFile.pdf -c ""[/CropBox [72 72 144 216] /PAGES pdfmark"" -f inFile.pdf";

         Process myProcess = new Process();
         myProcess.StartInfo = psi;
         myProcess.Start();

         myProcess.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
Unrecoverable error: undefinedfilename in setpagedevice
```

This is pretty cryptic, but googling around seems to suggest that it's related to failure to create the output file (outFile.pdf).

Comment: Try specifying a complete pathspec instead of just 'outFile.pdf'. Note that if you already have 'outFile.pdf' open then the command will fail because GS can't open the file for writing. You'll probably also have to specify the input file that way as well. I would guess that the problem is likely to do with the Current Working Directory not being correct.

Comment: @KenS:  Thanks for your help. I have tried numerous variations with different working directories and full pathnames. I finally decided to try calling the itextsharp API, instead, and that did work. But I'd like to understand what's wrong with my use of GS, and I need to call GS to get bounding boxes, anyway (which *does* work, thankfully).

Comment: Its hard to guess. First thing I;d do is remove -q, you don't really want to suppress messages when debugging. I'd expect the Ghostscript process to inherit the privileges of its parent (ie your process) but I don't write C# so I can't be sure. Perhaps the Process class documentation has more information on that. The error is returned from the PostScript environment and means that the specified device couldn't be opened. PostScript can't give you more information than that. If you can debug the child Ghostscript process I could tell you where to stop in the C code to look.

Comment: Another option of course would be to use Ghostscript.NET, which I know works, but it uses the DLL, it doesn't spawn a new process.

Comment: @KenS: Thanks again. When it says the "device" can't be opened, is it referring to the pdfwrite thing, or to the output file? Debugging the Ghostscript code would be way out of my league, I'm afraid. Maybe I'll try Ghostscript.NET. I have no desire to spawn a new process. I'm only doing that because I've seen it in lots of other examples.

Comment: Its referring to the pdfwrite device (set by -sDEVICE=). But that is failing to open because it can't open a file, presumably the output file. Presumably you can rebuild the Ghostscript executable, you are using Visual Studio, right ? So you could download the source, patch it to give you more error information (printf to stdout) and then rebuild and use that. Again I can give advice on making those modifications. One reason people use a process, rather than using the DLL, is to avoid the AGPL licencing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works. This is a work-in-progress, and I'm not a programmer, anyway, so please excuse the ugliness/goofiness. But it does the cropping using itextSharp, rather than Ghostscript. I'd still like to know what's wrong with the way I'm calling Ghostscript.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;

namespace pdfcropper
{
   class Program
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string[] config = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\public\pdfcropperConfig.txt");

         float d = float.Parse(config[0]);           // border size (n points)
         int show  =  int.Parse(config[1]);          // >0 to view after cropping; =0 to not
         string gspath = config[2];                  // path of Ghostscript executable

         string inFile  = args[0]; 

         float[] b = GetBounds(gspath, inFile);
         PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(b[0] - d, b[1] - d, b[2] + d, b[3] + d);

         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
         PdfDictionary pageDict  = reader.GetPageN(1);
         pageDict.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);

         string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
         string tempOutFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, "tempPDF.pdf");
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempOutFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

         // The "stamper" actually does the copying, when closed
         PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
         stamper.Close();

         reader.Close();

         // Replace original file by cropped one
         File.Copy(tempOutFile, inFile, true);
         File.Delete(tempOutFile);

         // Start Acrobat reader to view the output file
         if (show > 0) Process.Start(inFile);
      }

      private static float[] GetBounds(string gspath, string infilePath)
      {
         //string gspath = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64c.exe";

         ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
         psi.FileName = gspath;
         psi.UseShellExecute = false;
         psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
         psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
         psi.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(infilePath);
         psi.Arguments = @" -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q " + infilePath;

         Process proc = new Process();
         proc.StartInfo = psi;
         proc.Start();

         StreamReader myStreamReader = proc.StandardError;
         string output = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
         char sep = ' ';
         string output2 = output.Replace('\n', sep);
         string[] words = output2.Split(sep);

         float[] bounds = new float[4];

         bounds[0] = float.Parse(words[6]);    // xmin
         bounds[1] = float.Parse(words[7]);    // ymin
         bounds[2] = float.Parse(words[8]);    // xmax
         bounds[3] = float.Parse(words[9]);    // ymax

         proc.Close();

         return bounds;
      }

   }
}
```